# The time from a datetime-local input not being passed to the server in post request

Tags: python, django, forms, datetime

I have an input element that doesn't pass the time but just the date to the server to be stored in the database. I printed the start and end time from the POST request sent by the form and only the date gets sent even though the time has been entered.

2020-05-27T00:00
2020-05-30T00:00

Not sure why it's only grabbing the date. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help. My code is below.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="checkin">Check-in</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="checkin" name="checkin" placeholder="Check-in date">
</div>
```

Here's my model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    site = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(default='time', max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here's my view:

```
def addCustomer(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            start = request.POST.get('checkin')
            end = request.POST.get('checkout')
            lot = request.POST.get('lot')
            print(start)
            print(end)

            if name and start and end and lot:
                customer = Customer(name=name, site=lot, title=name, start=start, end=end)
                customer.save()
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Please make sure to fill out all the feilds.')
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        return redirect('loginuser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think you can use below code for start and end time

```
start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True) # When an object is created. This field is filled in automatically

end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True) # Whenever an object is modified. This field is filled in automatically and its value is changed
```

I hope it helps you